# Angular and Github API, CORS error when trying to exchange code for token

Tags: angular, typescript, github, cors, github-api

The authorization is successful, I get a code, and the GitHub redirects me back, everything is working as it should, but when I try to ask for an access_token using the code I've got, I always receive the same error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token due to access control checks.
```

As I understood this is a problem with CORS. I'm using Angular, and this is my code for the exchange:

```
const url = `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`;

const body = {
  client_id: this.clientId,
  client_secret: this.clientSecret,
  code: code,
  redirect_uri: this.redirectUri,
  state: state
};

const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
};

return this.http.post(url, body, options);
```

**I've previously tried:**

- To set up proxy, however I would like to solve the issue on the frontend side if possible
- Modify header options, I thought that there's something I should change
- Reading the documentation, but it doesn't write about this issue.

My main goal is to get the access token from GitHub using the temporary code that they provided me with.

Comment: If you ever write the word "secret" in frontend code you should pause for a moment and consider what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OAuth flow, the exchange of an authorization code for an access token happens on the back channel (server side).

So you should not write the exchange access token logic in Angular.

> The front channel flow is used by the client application to obtain an
> authorization code grant. The back channel is used by the client
> application to exchange the authorization code grant for an access
> token (and optionally a refresh token). - [source](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/21/what-the-heck-is-oauth#oauth-flows)

Recommended video to learn about OAuth 2.0: https://youtu.be/996OiexHze0